# add/edit in Kendo ui listview

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I want to use kendo ui listview in asp.net mvc

this is my view:

```
<div>
    <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-add-button" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-add"></span>Add New Blog</a>
</div>
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="product-view k-widget">
        <div class="edit-buttons">
            <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-edit-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-edit"></span></a>
            <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-delete-button" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span></a>
        </div>
        <dl>
            <dt>Subject</dt>
            <dd>#:Subject#</dd>

            <dt>Description</dt>
            <dd>#:Description#</dd>

            <dt>Address</dt>
            <dd>#:Address#</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</script>


<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().ListView<CreateUpdateBlogViewModel>()
          .Name("UserBlogs")
          .TagName("div")
                  .ClientTemplateId("template")
       .DataSource(dataSource =>
       {
           dataSource.Model(m =>
           {
               m.Id( i => i.Id);
               m.Field(f => f.Subject);
               m.Field(f => f.Address);
               m.Field(f => f.Description);
               m.Field(f => f.PageMode).Editable(false);
           });
           dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("UserBlogs_Read", "Webmaster"));
           dataSource.Update(update => update.Action("Editing_Update", "Webmaster"));
           dataSource.Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Editing_Destroy", "Webmaster"));
           dataSource.PageSize(1);
       })

          .Pageable().AutoBind(true)
          .Editable()
    )
</div>
```

My viewModel(CreateUpdateBlogViewModel) have properties(like Id , CreationDate , ...) that i dont want to show them to the user when he want to add or edit her blog 
i want user just edit Subject Description and Address and other property not shown

How can do this?

current just in display mode these three property shown and when i click on add or edit button all property of view model show and ready for editing

Comment: Did you try to set editable false for the non-editable fields.

Comment: yes but does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the editor template of the ListView like explained [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/listview/editing). Thus you can avoid creating editors at all for these fields.

Comment: According this link: 'http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/listview/editing.html' not used editor template but work fine

Comment: I read your link but cant understand where we introduce defined editor template to listview that use it for add and edit?can you show me an example

Comment: Grid is quite the same, check the documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/editor-templates) and for more info about the MVC template engine check the links that are given there.